# How to group samplers in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Im using jmeter to run a load test.
Is there a way to tell jmeter to group samples in listeners?
Example, using the following samples:

```
<code>
/home
/displayCategory?id=1
/displayCategory?id=2
/displayCategory?id=2
</code>
```

In the summary report i need to have:

```
<code>
Sampler     Response time
Home Page         13 
Category Page     34
Total             47
</code>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can add your sampler requests to logical controller, Transaction Controller:

Transaction Controller(Home Page)
  -> /home

Transaction Controller(Category Page)
  -> /displayCategory?id=1
  -> /displayCategory?id=2
  -> /displayCategory?id=2

This will get you the individual request details as well as combined details in Transaction Controller.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the "Generate Parent Sample" on the Transaction Controller only the Transaction Controller will be shown.  Looks like you would want to check this box.  If not you will see the transaction controller and the requests it contains.

I know this is not an answer, but a comment on the previous answer, apparently I do not have enough rep to comment.